# 'git lfs track' gives me incorrect "already supported" error

Tags: git-lfs

My `.gitattributes` file has a single line:

```
*.exe filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

`git lfs ls-files` shows me tracking 7 different *.exe files.

I want to track another file, which is already part of the repository.

When I execute the command `git lfs track "CacheFiles\Development_EntitlementFlatCache.dat` I get the error `"CacheFiles\\Development_EntitlementFlatCache.dat" already supported`.

I check my `.gitattributes` files, and it is unchanged.

When I try adding a different .dat file, it works fine.

Why might it be saying that this file is supported, when it isn't being tracked?  Why is it preventing me from tracking this *.dat file, but not other *.dat files?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that there was a `.gitattributes` file in the `CacheFiles` directory.

It really *was* tracking that file already.